# iphone UI forms and labels

Tags: iphone, user-interface

Just a general question here, I have an iPhone app that has 3 textfields on a view. What is best practice for displaying 'form elements' and 'labels'?

Coming from a web background I have automatically used labels (above the textfields) & textfields on my UI, but should i get rid of my labels and use the placeholder property of the textfields instead?

the app target audience will be varied demographics and i envisage a lot of newbie iphone users using the app.

thanks
kb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, placeholder text is the way to go. For an example, go to the Calendar app, tap on the + button at the top-right, & select 'Title Location'. You will see something similar to what you are trying.